# Some LESS variables not working

Tags: less

I'm creating a custom theme inheriting from Magento Blank. I'm overriding LESS variables in my theme.less file. Must are working fine, but there are a few that arn't working. Example; Neither @breadcrumbs__padding nor @actions-toolbar-actions__reverse work.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I don't get an error. Any value applied to the variable simply has no effect.

Comment: Are you working locally?  Do you see the changes that you made updated inside the css file once you compile via grunt?

Comment: Had no end of problems trying to get grunt working and ended up giving up. I'm using client-side LESS compilation. I can see the effect of changing most of the variables, but there are just a few that don't work. My suspicion is that they don't end up getting used in the mixins.